# System hacked LD Preload modifies /usr/bin/host

Tags: linux, sh

Our system got hacked.

The attackers use LD_Preload to preload a .so file in order to modify the standard /usr/bin/host file.

After modified it lauchnes bruteforce attacks.

Anybody knows how I can see the LD_Preload settings loaded in the environment for a specific user ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should provide more details how you set it up.

Comment: I just want to see the ENV for user Apache. There should be a LD_PRELOAD setting.

Nothing pops up when I :

sudo -Hiu apache env

Comment: Nothing may pop-up if you only run `env`. The environment settings could also depend on the shell that the user loads. For example with bash, other global files and user files are loaded like /etc/profile and ~/.bashrc, etc. when it runs.

Comment: Try `find /proc/ -type f -name environ -readable | xargs grep -HFe LD_PRELOAD`. And that's probably better done as a superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script to search for values in the environment of a process enumerated with username.

```
#!/bin/sh
ID=$(id -u "$1") && \
for DIR in /proc/[0-9]*; do
    [ -d "$DIR" ] && [ -r "$DIR/environ" ] && [ -r "$DIR/loginuid" ] || continue
    read I < "$DIR/loginuid"; [ "$I" -eq "$ID" ] || continue
    echo "---- $DIR ----"
    grep -zZhFe LD_PRELOAD "$DIR/environ" | tr '\0' '\n'
done
```

Usage:

```
sh script.sh apache
```

And you can use this to search in all processes:

```
#!/bin/sh
for DIR in /proc/[0-9]*; do
    [ -d "$DIR" ] && [ -r "$DIR/environ" ] || continue
    echo "---- $DIR ----"
    grep -zZhFe LD_PRELOAD "$DIR/environ" | tr '\0' '\n'
done
```